# How to retrieve detail object from mongodb using classic django urls and views?

Tags: django, mongodb, django-filter, djongo

I'm working on recording server access log into mongodb database; I'm able to record server access log into mongodb database and also able to list all recorded logs applying django-filter in rest api view. But when I'm wondering if there is a possible way to retrieve log detail so that I can use django provided RetrieveUpdateAPIView.

I'm using djongo and my log models is

```
from djongo import models as mongo_models

class AccessLog(mongo_models.Model):
    _id = mongo_models.ObjectIdField()
    user_id = mongo_models.BigIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    user_email = mongo_models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    path = mongo_models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=True, null=True)
    method = mongo_models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    data = mongo_models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    ip_address = mongo_models.CharField(max_length=45, null=True, blank=True)
    status_code = mongo_models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    flag = mongo_models.BooleanField(default=False)
    remarks = mongo_models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = mongo_models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = mongo_models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

And my log list views

```
class AccessLogListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (AccessLogPermissions, )
    filter_backends = [
        filters.SearchFilter,
        DjangoFilterBackend
    ]
    filterset_fields = [
        'user_id',
        'user_email',
        'method',
        'ip_address',
        'status_code',
        'flag',
    ]
    search_fields = [
        'remarks',
    ]
    serializer_class = AccessLogSerializer
    queryset = AccessLog.objects.all()
```

And my detail views as

```
class AccessLogUpdateView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (AccessLogPermissions,)
    lookup_field = '_id'
    serializer_class = AccessLogUpdateSerializer
    queryset = AccessLog.objects.all()
```

And urls.py as

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.AccessLogListView.as_view(), name='list-access-log'),
    path('<str:_id>/', views.AccessLogUpdateView.as_view(), name='update-access-log'),
]
```

When I try to get by _id the django throws 404 error. Also when I try to add _id field in list views as a filter field it throws and error non existing field _id. It will be possible to extract url paramas and query directly to mongo db database but I'm seeking if there is a way to retrieve and update document as normal way that is to be used for relational databases.

**Update**

I added extra uuid field in the log models and changed url and lookup_field in views as uuid and it's working.

Comment: what version of django and djongo are you using?  i am having issues with makemigrations.

Comment: @ThomasDKim I'm using Django==3.2.7 and djongo==1.3.6